# Complex number (square) root notation.

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

A mathematician told me that the notation $\sqrt{a+bi}$ isn't used, instead we use $w=z^2$ and substitute. Is this correct? If yes, is there any particular reason we don't want imaginary numbers under a root sign?

Comment: Well by definition when you take a square root, you have a positive one and a negative one, so writing a square root with no sign is certainly not correct regardless of whether you deal with complex numbers or reals.

Comment: The 2 expressions are not equivalent. $\sqrt .$ is a function, and has one value, $w=z^2$ has 2 solutions. You can use that notation but your number would be defined $[\pi]$

Comment: The notation $\sqrt{a+bi}$ can be used, but one has to define which branch of the square root one is using before one uses it. E.g., if you say, $\sqrt z$ is defined for all complex $z$ except negative reals, and has argument between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, then you can use $\sqrt{a+bi}$ with abandon.

Comment: One may argue that the notation $\sqrt{z}$ brings no practical advantage and that, each time one would be tempted to use it, the alternative to say that $w^2=z$ (with some further specification on $w$) is preferable. Additionally, if one insists on using the notation $\sqrt{z}$, then another danger arises, which is that the identity $$\sqrt{z_1}\cdot\sqrt{z_2}=\sqrt{z_1z_2}$$ stops to be guaranteed, *even if $\sqrt{\ }$ was carefully defined on a suitable domain*, for example by halving the argument taken in $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: In fact, my question was for known $a,b$, dunno if it changes anything.

Answer (score 2):

In general the equation 
$$z^2=w$$
has two (complex) solutions $z_1$ and $z_2=-z_1$.

In the case $w$ is real and positive, the solutions are real. Thus exactly one solution is positive and one solution is negative. It is then possible to assign $\sqrt{w}$ to the positive solution.

Return to the general complex case, $\Bbb C$ cannot be equipped with an order as $\Bbb R$. The two solutions $z_1$ and $z_2$ are now more equivalent. It is then not natural, even impossible, to assign $\sqrt{w}$ to either of the two solutions.

Comment: It is certainly *possible* to make a choice of $z$ for each $w$, and frequently people do and denote the function by $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and call the resulting function "square root". But, like you say, it is easier to fall prey to mistakes in the complex case, and one really ought to specify which choice they're making before using this symbol and term.

Answer (score 2):

To write $\sqrt{z}$ for one of the two, or for both, complex square roots of complex number is perfectly fine, apart from the inescapable ambiguity. It certainly expresses the intent. In many contexts, further clarification would be needed to specify *which* of the two square roots, perhaps depending on how $z$ moved along a path or within a region.

Comment: I agree completely. There's nothing wrong with the notation, as long as you are aware of the ambiguity. The ambiguity is resolved by writing $\pm\sqrt{z}$ if you are trying to keep track of both roots, since there is only one other root and it is *always* the opposite of the first root (and no harm is done if it is zero). +1.